# How to invoke three ajax functions together?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Below is the code in my asp page

**Ajax.asp**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Ajax.asp</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Delay(SECOND)
{
var xmlHttp;
try
  {  
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }
catch (e)
  { 
   try
    {    
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");   
     }
  catch (e)
    {   
     try
      {     
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
          }
    catch (e)
      {      
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");      
      return false; 
           }    
           } 
            }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
      { 
    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);     
      }
    }   
    xmlHttp.open("GET","Delay_Page.asp?SECOND="+SECOND,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
    return true
   }
</script>
</head>

<body>

// below is the button for passing seconds 

<input onclick="javascript:return (Delay('30')&& Delay('10')&& Delay('5'));" type="button" value="Button" name="B3">
</body>

</html>
```

In the **Delay_Page.asp**  this is the code

```
<%
ss= request.querystring("SECOND")

Sub Delay(DelaySeconds)
SecCount = 0
Sec2 = 0
While SecCount < DelaySeconds + 1
Sec1 = Second(Time())
If Sec1 <> Sec2 Then
Sec2 = Second(Time())
SecCount = SecCount + 1
End If
Wend 
End Sub

Delay(SECOND)

response.write SECOND &" SECONDS left"
%>
```

The above code is working fine, but some problems i wants to solve

what i need is

i want to invoke `Delay('30')&& Delay('10')&& Delay('5'))`  functions together

Now the condition is, when the first function finish `Delay('30')` then after only it goes to the second function

Now Total time to finish the function is 45 seconds (30 + 10 + 5)

I need to finish these three functions in 30 seconds

hoping your help plz,

Comment: You should really look into something like jQuery to handle your ajax calls... doing try/catch with ActiveX objects only covers IE browsers and the jQuery implementation works with all major platforms without any real complex code on your end.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see where your problem is, so it must be in your asp page. I'm sorry to say that I can't have a way of testing asp at the moment, so I can't help there. but, I wrote a fake delay in PHP and run your javascript. Here's what I used to test:

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['SECOND'])) {


    for($i=0;$i<$_GET['SECOND']*100000;$i++) {
        $x = sqrt($i);
    }
    echo $_GET['SECOND'].': x='.$x;
    die();
}

?>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Ajax.asp</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Delay(SECOND)
{
var xmlHttp;
try
  {  
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }
catch (e)
  { 
   try
    {    
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");   
     }
  catch (e)
    {   
     try
      {     
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
          }
    catch (e)
      {      
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");      
      return false; 
           }    
           } 
            }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
      { 
     document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += xmlHttp.responseText + "<br />";     
      }
    }   
    xmlHttp.open("GET","ajax-test.php?SECOND="+SECOND,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
    return true
   }
</script>
</head>

<body>

// below is the button for passing seconds 

<input onclick="javascript:return (Delay('30')&& Delay('10')&& Delay('5'));" type="button" value="Button" name="B3">
<div id='output'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The PHP part (at the top) basically is just to waste some time, depending on the SECONDS value. Though, it really only takes about 1/6th the amount of time requested. Here is the output from running the script:

```
5: x=707.106074079
10: x=999.9995
30: x=1732.05051889
```

Basically, this is just showing that 5 DELAY(5) is returning before DELAY(10) which is returning before DELAY(30), even though they are being requested in the opposite order.

So, take a look at your asp delay code, as the problem must be there. Sorry I can't help much otherwise.

Comment: thanks...
what i need is , i wand to invock (Delay('30')&& Delay('10')&& Delay('5') these functions parallel

Comment: @Alex: You *are* running the requests in parallel, except possibly for browser limitations. (some browsers limit the number of connections to two per host)